# Prove $\int f\log\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)\,d\nu\geq 0$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

Let $f$ and $g$ be positive integrable functions on a measure space with a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$.
If
$$
\int f\,d\nu\geq \int g\,d\nu>0,
$$
then one can show that
$$
\int f\log\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)\,d\nu\geq 0.
$$

---

Let
$$
A=\left\{f\geq g\right\}\quad\text{and}\quad B= \left\{f<g\right\},
$$
then we have
$$
\int_A\left(f-g\right)\,d\nu\geq \int_B\left(g-f\right)\,d\nu.
$$
Then I don't know how to relate this result to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\log x \geq 1 - (1/x)$, so $$f \log(f/g) \geq f \Bigl(1-\frac{g}{f}\Bigr) = f-g.$$ Now integrate with respect to $\nu$.